# How to group by using 2 columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query in MySQL database

```
SELECT tbl_lab_reservations.full_desc, serial_number, rsvn_owner, reservation_id, 
SUM((SELECT DATEDIFF(reservation_date_end, reservation_date_start)+1)) AS totalNumberOfDaysReserve FROM tbl_lab_reservations 
JOIN tbl_lab_assets ON tbl_lab_assets.id = tbl_lab_reservations.lab_id 
WHERE tbl_lab_reservations.full_desc = 'WMHD (Masthead Amplifier)' 
AND tbl_lab_reservations.asset_status = 'Idle' 
GROUP BY rsvn_owner 
ORDER BY `tbl_lab_reservations`.`rsvn_owner` ASC
```

and this is the result

[image: query result]

the result is correct base on the query but it is not what I want.
Base on my data save on the database, there should be another `rsvn_owner` named PAYAK but the problem is PAYAK uses `serial_numbers` which is also used by IT so because it is grouped by serial number the `totalNumberOfDaysReserve` of PAYAK and IT are added which makes it wrong.
What I want is the query is grouped by `serial_number` but if they belong to different `rsvn_owner` they should create another row.

Hope somebody undestands and can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so just try to group by serial number and after that by owner? :)

```
GROUP BY serial_number, rsvn_owner
```

like this

```
SELECT
  tbl_lab_reservations.full_desc, serial_number, rsvn_owner, reservation_id,
  SUM((SELECT DATEDIFF(reservation_date_end, reservation_date_start)+1)) AS totalNumberOfDaysReserve
FROM tbl_lab_reservations
JOIN tbl_lab_assets ON tbl_lab_assets.id = tbl_lab_reservations.lab_id
WHERE tbl_lab_reservations.full_desc = 'WMHD (Masthead Amplifier)'
  AND tbl_lab_reservations.asset_status = 'Idle'
GROUP BY serial_number, rsvn_owner
ORDER BY `tbl_lab_reservations`.`rsvn_owner`
```

AS syntax tell us (see near comma)

```
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
```

we can do this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I wonder when I tried it on my own lately it doesn't fix but now its ok.